# SQL query that limits the results to one when using count inside count

Tags: mysql, join, count

I am trying to select the count of likes on a specific project. The idea i came up with is

```
CAST(count(uploads.ID in (SELECT uploadID from votes)) as decimal) as numberoflikes
```

this works but the query then only returns one thing.

Entire query

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.NAME AS username
    ,users.ID AS userID
    ,subjects.NAME AS subjectname
    ,uploads.TIME
    ,uploads.description
    ,uploads.NAME
    ,uploads.ID
    ,CASE 
        WHEN uploads.ID IN (
                SELECT uploadID
                FROM votes
                WHERE userID = 2
                )
            THEN CAST(1 AS DECIMAL)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS DECIMAL)
        END AS liked
    ,CASE 
        WHEN uploads.ID IN (
                SELECT uploadID
                FROM bookmarks
                WHERE userID = 2
                )
            THEN CAST(1 AS DECIMAL)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS DECIMAL)
        END AS bookmarked
    ,CAST(count(uploads.ID IN (
                SELECT uploadID
                FROM votes
                )) AS DECIMAL) AS numberoflikes
FROM uploads
INNER JOIN subjects ON (subjects.ID = uploads.subjectID)
INNER JOIN users ON (users.ID = uploads.userID)
INNER JOIN uploadGrades ON (uploads.ID = uploadGrades.uploadID)
INNER JOIN grades ON (grades.ID = uploadGrades.gradeID)
WHERE uploads.active = 1
    AND subjects.ID IN (
        SELECT subjectID
        FROM userSubjects
        INNER JOIN users ON (users.ID = userSubjects.userID)
        WHERE userSubjects.userID = 2
        )
    AND grades.ID IN (
        SELECT userGrades.gradeID
        FROM uploadGrades
        INNER JOIN userGrades ON (uploadGrades.gradeID = userGrades.gradeID)
        WHERE userGrades.userID = 2
        )
ORDER BY uploads.trueRating DESC;
```

Comment: I think I'd be tempted to bin this one and start again. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: The "in" clause is supremely inefficient.  You really need to rewrite this to use joins instead.  Even using one "in" is dicey; I count no less than five of them here.  As your database grows, this query will grind down to a crawl.

Comment: The query works. i know that the in clause is inefficient, i dont realy expect the database to grow a hole lot. but the problem i am having is that when this line "CAST(count(uploads.ID in (SELECT uploadID from votes)) as decimal) as numberoflikes"
is added the query only returns one result.

Comment: So you want a count of votes per upload?  I will rewrite the query for that with joins instead of in clauses.

Comment: I dont think that will work, because `IN` is a expresion returning `TRUE/FALSE` and `COUNT` will count anything not `NULL` so will count `true and false`

Comment: yes, it is a different number for each upload. they have different amounts of likes. Now i do this in the program it self but that works very slowly. @JuanCarlosOropeza it was working for me but only returning one thing.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - not if you use a join correctly, it can do the same thing that an in expression does, only a thousand times more efficient, and a proper join also clarifies what you are trying to do and usually removes the very kind of problem Omar is having getting the query to work right.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Sorry my comment was direct to OP.  I dont think his `COUNT` do what he want to do. I agree with `JOIN` and I post one answer with that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try a reduce version of your query, That is the base to get better answers

1. I reduce the initial query to `user` and `upload` to start. Also remove the fields you already know how to calculate.

.

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.NAME AS username
    ,users.ID AS userID
    ,uploads.NAME
    ,uploads.ID
    ,CAST(count(uploads.ID IN (
                SELECT uploadID
                FROM votes
                )) AS DECIMAL) AS numberoflikes
FROM uploads
INNER JOIN users ON (users.ID = uploads.userID)
WHERE uploads.active = 1
ORDER BY uploads.trueRating DESC;
```

2. Then add votes with `LEFT JOIN` to replace the `SELECT` in the `COUNT` that way if not match you will get `NULL` and as I say in my comment `COUNT` doesnt count `NULL's`

.

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.NAME AS username
    ,users.ID AS userID
    ,uploads.NAME
    ,uploads.ID
    ,CAST(count(votes.uploadID)) AS DECIMAL) AS numberoflikes
FROM uploads
INNER JOIN users ON (users.ID = uploads.userID)
LEFT JOIN votes ON (uploads.ID = votes.uploadID)
WHERE uploads.active = 1
ORDER BY uploads.trueRating DESC;
```

Comment: I tried the inner join version and i am still getting the same error. It only returns one row of data.

Comment: Then is something else, can you create a working sample in http://SqlFiddle.com  ??

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
SELECT users.name as username, users.ID as userID, subjects.name as subjectname,
       uploads.time, uploads.description, uploads.name, uploads.ID, 
       count(userVotes.userId), count(bookmarksMade.userId),
FROM uploads 
     join subjects     on(subjects.ID = uploads.subjectID) 
     join users        on(users.ID = uploads.userID)
     join uploadGrades on(uploads.ID = uploadGrades.uploadID) 
     join grades       on(grades.ID = uploadGrades.gradeID)
     left join (select userId, uploadId from votes where userId = 2) as userVotes on uploads.id = userVotes.uploadId
     left join (select userId, uploadId from bookmarks where userId = 2) as bookmarksMade on uploads.id = bookmarksMade.uploadId
     join userSubjects on subjects.id = userSubjects.subjectID
WHERE uploads.active = 1 AND 
      userSubjects.userID = 2
ORDER BY uploads.trueRating DESC;
```

But, I am leaving out the userGrades thing, because you are doing a funky join there that I don't really understand (joining two tables on something that looks like it is not the whole primary key on either table).

Anyway, you really need to go to something more like this or what Oropeza suggests in his answer.  Get more direct about what you want.  This query looks like a monster that has been growing and getting things added in with "IN" clauses, as you needed them.  Time to go back to the drawing board and think about what you want and how to get at it directly.

Comment: This query only returns one row. Thanks for the effort tough.+

Answer (score 0):

count(uploads.ID in (SELECT uploadID from votes)) as numberoflikes

group by uploads.Id ORDER BY uploads.trueRating DESC

I managed to do it like this. If i added the group by then it split the numberoflikes into rows and returned more then one row. Thanks for the help!